# E212: Can't open file for writing, i must use sudo,Is there any other way

Tags: debian

i used vim to create **sa.sh** in **/home/guoyanzhang**, when i used **:wq**, a warning appers as follows:

```
"sa.sh" E212: Can't open file for writing
Press ENTER or type command to continue

my system infomation is as follows:

guoyanzhang@debian:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster
guoyanzhang@debian:~$ whoami
guoyanzhang
guoyanzhang@debian:~$ ls -l /home/
total 4
dr-xr-xr-x 10 guoyanzhang guoyanzhang 4096 Aug 11 02:07 guoyanzhang
guoyanzhang@debian:~$ touch sa.sh
touch: cannot touch 'sa.sh': Permission denied
```

Comment: This is about Debian. This site is for Ubuntu. Thus, this is [off-topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic). There's a SE site for other Linux/Unix distros [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This indicates that the file was not created by user "guoyanzhang", or if it is a new file that you want to create, you have a problem with the permissions of your `home` folder.

In your `home` you can also simply test a `touch file.test`, if you have the same problem it will confirm the problem.

Do an `ls -l /home` to see the permissions of your `home` folder.

if the rights are incorrect you will need to use `sudo` to change them.

Comment: I add some informations，and how to change？

Comment: So...yes... you have change the defaut rights,  :(  so do :  "sudo chmod u=rwx g=rx o=rx /home/guoyanzhang"    I hope you haven't done this kind of left and right "manipulation" ... otherwise your system will become completely unstable

Comment: for verification... do a: "ls -la /home/guoyanzhang"  to see if it's not recursive